# NativeScript Development Environment at MacBook m1

Tags: nativescript, environment, apple-m1

I am trying to set up the development environment on a new MacBook Air (with m1 CPU). I follow the setup instructions from the official [website](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#windows-ios).

When I run the 'ns doctor ios' all seems to be fine, however when I run the 'ns run ios' I am getting the following error:

Installing pods...
arch: posix_spawnp: pod: Bad CPU type in executable
'arch install' command failed.

I mention that I tried to run the additional commands for the m1
"sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi"
"arch -x86_64 pod install"
However, I received the same error.

Could you have any suggestions about this situation?

Comment: I found the solution. The issue was that I did not installed the homebrew properly. The homebrew should be installed on /usr/local/ folder. I found the path that had been installed by using the command 'which -a brew'. After I found that is not to the proper path I uninstalled it and installed it again properly. Now works fine.